# IIS Management Console Refused to show up

Tags: iis

I am Windows 10 Pro Build 18363. I have run into a strange problem with the IIS Management Console.

**The Problem:**

The console has been fine until recently. The problem is that the manager window does not show up after I launch it through inetmgr or from the Administrative Tools. What I am getting now is an IIS icon on the Task bar, not the Manager window.

See the pictures below. They are what I am getting now. If I click the "Internet Information Services" again, another IIS instance opens. See the second picture. Clicking on either of the blank small window does not do anything.

**What I have done:**

1. I tried to remove it using the Turn Windows Features On and Off and add it back in. That did not help.
2. Rebooted several times to no avail.
3. Googled it several days but did not find matching scenarios.

Thanks for your great insight!

John

[image: This is what I am getting now.]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

1. Press WINDOWS + R.
2. Type "gpedit.msc" without quotes and press ENTER.
3. Click "Administrative Templates" under "User Configuration"
4. Click "Start and taskbar"
5. Double click "Disable taskbar previews"
6. Click "Enable", Click "Apply", Reboot.

Comment: Thank you, @samwu. I am not sure if my issue is related to the Taskbar Previews" feature but my computer does not even that option when I tried to follow your instructions. Wish there was an option for me to upload a screenshot here. I only see one option with "Disable context menus in the Start Menu".

Answer (score 0):

I did a little digging after I posted my comment and figured out what the problem was. I posted what I did here, hoping to help someone.

I right-clicked one of the white blank thumbnails to bring up the context menu and chose the maximize item. That was it!

Thank you.

[image]